# How to create a mask with parameters from the pipeline source code automatically in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have some pipelines in Jenkins (storeed on github) and they successfully work when run.
All of these pipelines have the own set of parameters written in this way:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        ...
    }
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'TEST', defaultValue: false, description: 'Run task in test mode')
        choice(name: 'TASK', choices: ['REFRESH', 'BUILD'], description: 'Pick task')
    }
...
}
```

However the mask is not automatically reflected on the Jenkins server unless I manually use the option in `Configure` *General -> This project is parameterised* and add all the variable singularly (duplication of work).

Is there any way to make Jenkins able to build the mask form the coded committed on Github (or any Git server)?

Comment: What do you mean by a mask?

Comment: UI interface checkboxes drop down lists etc